# Select multipl element list rendering with v-for - Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, v-for

I need to create a list which allow multiple selects on a list rendering.
Actually, I tried to set a handle selection on my code but it selects only one element at a time.

My code :

```html
<template>
  <div class="length">
    <input
      v-model="searchTool"
      type="text"
      class="input-search"
      placeholder="Rechercher du matériel"
    />
    <section
      v-for="result in filteredList"
      id="flex-wrapper"
      :key="result.id"
      :class="selectedTool.id === result.id ? 'active' : ''"
      @click="handleSelect(result)"
    >
      <div class="first part">
        <div class="tools">
          {{ result.reference }}+ {{ result.designation }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      results: '',
      searchTool: '',
      selectedTool: {},
    }
  },

  computed: {
    filteredList() {
      if (this.searchTool === '') {
        return this.results
      }
      return this.results.filter(
        (post) =>
          post.designation
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.searchTool.toLowerCase()) ||
          post.reference.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTool.toLowerCase())
      )
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$axios
      .get('/api/tools')
      .then((res) => {
        this.results = res.data
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.results))
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
      })
  },
  methods: {
    handleSelect(element) {
      this.selectedTool = element
      console.log(this.selectedTool)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure to fully understand what you're trying to achieve here. You want some kind of checkbox selection or some filtering based on keystrokes? For the first one, give a read to this part: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#checkbox

Comment: I've checked the link, i 'll try something with it but i' m not sure if it's what i want. Because i want an input where i can search some items from api. Those items, i want to select multipl of them in order to create a list

Comment: Try to phrase/draw what you initially want on paper. Then it will probably be more clear for us and for yourself too.

Comment: When i was rethinking about it, i found another better solution ! Thank you for your help.

Comment: I will put the selected item into an array, so every new items selected  will get store there. And i'll show this array content on a div in order to show it.

Comment: I'd recommend using an array of objects, with a `isSelected` boolean state rather than a simple array to check if it's selected or not. Will be less messy overall.